# How to write this raw query in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a sql query, and i want to know if it can be written in eloquent.

There are two tables Brands and Products.

I am trying to get the brands which are in particular category of products

Below is how it looks currently

```
\DB::select('select * FROM brands WHERE id in ( select brand_id from products WHERE category_id IN (220, 222, 223) GROUP by brand_id )');
```

The above is working, i want help on  converting it to eloquent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've already prepped `Brand` and `Product` models, you can specify closure to include subquery inside your `WHERE IN` clause like this:

```
Brand::whereIn('id', function ($query) {
    $query
        ->select('brand_id')
        ->from('products')
        ->whereIn('category_id', [220, 222, 223])
        ->groupBy('brand_id');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to have your models set up so you can query them using Eloquent; when you have those you can do:

```
$categoryIds = [220, 222, 223];

$brandIds = Product::whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds)
                ->groupBy('brand_id')
                ->pluck('brand_id');

$yourQuery = Brand::whereIn('id', $brandIds)->get();
```

Comment: This will issue two separate queries instead of one.

Comment: Yes. Which is why yours is better :)

Comment: i knew how to do like this, but wanted to avoid running the extra query. @d3jn helped with nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have your model Brand and Products to do it you will do:
$brands = Brand::with(['category'=>function($query){ $query->select('category_id')}])->whereIn('category_id',[220, 222, 223])->get();